# Ubuntu installation failed and left apt broken

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, 17.04

I've been trying to get Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 and finally got it to boot, however it failed near the end of the installation leaving my `apt` repositories not set up correctly. Hopefully this is the only part that failed, however I am just taking this one step at a time. This is what it says when I try to update:

```
CorruptComputer@Ubuntu-GNOME:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for CorruptComputer: 
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412) zesty InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412) zesty Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease            
Reading package lists... Done                                  
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412) zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: The only error is about *cd-rom*, about the media you used to install. You can (and should) remove or disable it safely. Settings > Software & Updates > Other software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by following the same steps in the answer here: [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)